# Cocoa Project Error

Tags: cocoa

my project jumped out this error code from Xcode. It is for OS X. How do I solve this?

```
2013-03-11 20:39:12.804 Project1[2038:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
   (
        "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x101a1e8e0 h=--& v=--& H:    [NSView:0x100130d40(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10013a5d0 H:[NSScrollView:0x1001310b0]-(17)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100130d40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1001382c0 H:|-(17)-[NSScrollView:0x1001310b0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100130d40 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10013a5d0 H:[NSScrollView:0x1001310b0]-(17)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100130d40 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2013-03-11 20:39:12.806 Project1[2038:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x101a1e9a0 h=--& v=--& V:[NSView:0x100130d40(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10013a630 V:|-(102)-[NSScrollView:0x1001310b0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100130d40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x100138320 V:[NSScrollView:0x1001310b0]-(17)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100130d40 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x100138320 V:[NSScrollView:0x1001310b0]-(17)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x100130d40 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion the log messages gave you? "Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES"

Comment: yes, let me try again

Answer (score 1):

You have set your own auto-layout constraint that is conflicting with your other constraint.

This happens as :

If you set the difference between two buttons as 10 and from window border as 20. But your button sees that it is not 20 from window border and it can not move towards the border since your other constraint is 10.

[image]

Comment: so do I just try to merger stuff closer to solve the problem?

Comment: be confident to check H/V:|-(17)-| are cood and doesn't make any ambiguity to the UI generator.